# Find the derivative and integral of the following function

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm a bit confused on how to work out this question, so if you could show working it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

> Find $f'(x)$ and $\int f(x)\,dx$ for
>   $$f(x)= 4\left(3-\cosh\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\right)$$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: You need to know how differentiate $4x$, $3-x$, $cosh(x)$ and $x/5$ can you do this? If you can then you need to know how differentiation works with the composition of functions. Once you know that you can evaluate the derivative in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

- Find $f'(x)$:

$$f'(x)=\frac{\text{d}f(x)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(4\left(3-\cosh\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\right)\right)=$$
$$4\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(3\right)-\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\cosh\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\right)=-4\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\cosh\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\right)$$

Now, use the chain rule:

$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cosh\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\right)=\frac{\text{d}\cosh(u)}{\text{d}u}\cdot\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}$ where $u=\frac{x}{5}$ and $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}u}\left(\cosh(u)\right)=\sinh(u)$

---

- Find $\int f(x)\space\text{d}x$:

$$\int4\left(3-\cosh\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=4\left[\int3\space\text{d}x-\int\cosh\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\space\text{d}x\right]$$

Now, substitute $u=\frac{x}{5}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{5}\space\text{d}x$.

And notice that the antiderivative of $\cosh(x)$ is $\sinh(x)$.